# How can I allow the user to select across an editable div and a non editable div

Tags: reactjs

I have a div that is editable. I then also have a div below it that is not. I want to allow the user to be able to select both of these so they can copy the text and paste it somewhere else.

```html
<div contenteditable="true">This text should be editable</div>

    <div
      style={{
      margin: 2,
      borderRadius: 10,
      padding: 10,
      backgroundColor: "Red",
      }}
    >
    This code should be selectable
    </div>
```

However, the user is stopped at the end of the editable div. I tried putting the whole thing within an editable div and setting the red div's "contenteditable" to false and that allowed the user to select both sets of text, but it also allowed the user to delete the red div by backspacing or clicking the delete key.

```html
<div
          contenteditable="true"
          style={{
            margin: "auto",
            width: "90%",
            height: "90%",
            overflow: "scroll",
          }}
        >
          This text should be editable
          <div
            contenteditable="false"
            style={{
              margin: 2,
              borderRadius: 10,
              padding: 10,
              backgroundColor: "Red",
            }}
          >            
            THIS CODE SHOULD NOT BE ABLE TO BE DELETED
          </div>
          This text should be editable
        </div>
```

I'm using Reactjs

Comment: Not sure what you mean by selectable. Can you describe the scenarios for this? For example, the user double clicks and highlights the contenteditable text and the non-editable text is highlighted together. Is this the outcome you are finding?

Comment: I want the user to be able to select both set of texts; the one that is editable, and one that can not. The first example, I can't select both set of texts at the same time. The second example I can, but the user can accidentally delete the non editable text buy backspacing.